Pip installing C++ project gives CMake Error
I'm trying to pip install KenLM into my conda environment through GitBash, because I need to import a module and later run inference on it. Doing so requires me to run the following command.
$ CMAKE_GENERATOR="NMake Makefiles JOM" pip install https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/archive/master.zip

When I run the code, I get the following error. How can I fix this?
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
    Generator

      NMake Makefiles JOM

    does not support platform specification, but platform

      x64

    was specified.


  CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

